# Generating 64kbps audio-only mpegts for HTTP Live segmenter to meet 64kbps audio only requirement

Tags: iphone, http, streaming, ffmpeg, mp4

I am trying to convert our mp4 files into mpeg-ts and segment it into .ts files for my iphone app to play.  I am using Carson McDonalds's HTTP-Live-Video-Stream-Segmenter-and-Distributor to do that.

I got his stuff complied and working correctly.  I am currently trying to meet Apple's requirement where I need to provide a baseline 64 kbps audio only stream to my m3u8 playlist.
Carson doesn't seem to have a profile for that.

I need to be able to generate 64kbps audio-only stream from mp4, and turn that into mpeg-ts for the segmenter into ts.  I am trying to find the right ffmpeg command that will validate without problem using Apple's mediastreamvalidator.

So far I modified an existing encoding profile to try to achieve 64kbps total:

ffmpeg -er 4 -i %s -f mpegts -acodec libmp3lame -ar 22050 -ab 32k -s 240x180 -vcodec libx264 -b 16k -flags +loop+mv4 -cmp 256 -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -subq 7 -trellis 1 -refs 5 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 64k -maxrate 16k -bufsize 16k -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 30 -aspect 4:3 -r 10 -g 30 -async 2 - | %s %s %s %s %s

but then when I try to validate it using mediastreamvalidator, it gives error after few ts:

Playlist Validation: OK

Segments:

sample_cell_4x3_64k-00001.ts:

WARNING: Media segment exceeds target duration of 10.00 seconds by 1.30 seconds (segment duration is 11.30 seconds)

sample_cell_4x3_64k-00002.ts:

WARNING: Media segment exceeds target duration of 10.00 seconds by 1.40 seconds (segment duration is 11.40 seconds)

....
....

sample_cell_4x3_64k-00006.ts:

ERROR: (-1) Unknown video codec: 1836069494 (program 0, track 0)
ERROR: (-1) failed to parse segment as either an MPEG-2 TS or an ES

sample_cell_4x3_64k-00007.ts:

ERROR: (-1) Unknown video codec: 1836069494 (program 0, track 0)
ERROR: (-1) failed to parse segment as either an MPEG-2 TS or an ES

....
....
Average segment duration: 10.26 seconds
Average segment bitrate: 376797.92 bps
Average segment structural overhead: 349242.17 bps (92.69 %)

Is there someway I can generate this correctly with just audio which totals 64kbps and turn it into mpeg-ts ready to be segmented and validated correctly?

Am I approaching the problem right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember all the details of Carson's ruby scripts, but the first thing I would do to get an audio-only stream is to stop the video processing (-vn). So something like this:

```
ffmpeg -er 4 -i %s -f mpegts -acodec libmp3lame -ar 22050 -ab 32k -vn - | %s %s %s %s %s
```